# C# struct pass by reference clarification and representation of variables of struct datatype in memory

Tags: c#, struct, types, reference

Just two small questions but consider the following code:

```
struct Wow
{
    public int nice;
    public int nices;
    public int nicess;
}

Wow amazing;
amazing.nice = 90;
amazing.nices = 90;
amazing.nicess = 90;
static void newfunct(ref Wow wow) {
    wow.nice = 300;
    Console.WriteLine(wow.nice);
};
newfunct(ref amazing);
Console.WriteLine(amazing.nice);
```

1. **When I pass a struct by ref, does it mean that in this case the variable wow will contain a pointer** (if you could call it a pointer, but you get what I mean) **to place in stack where the variables are grouped together, or will it just pass the pointer of each variable and value in stack to each variable of wow, I think it's the second one**?
2. **If I'd compare amazing and wow, would it give a result as being the same, if so does it just check if all the variables of wow and amazing are at the same place in stack memory** **with their values** (in this case) **or is because the struct has kind of its own memory space where the variables also have separate memory locations?** If I'm not being clear with this question just let me know, but I don't really know any other way to reformulate my question currently.

Have an amazing day!

Comment: "the struct has kind of its own memory space": yes, it has. The compiler will not decompose it in any way when passing it to the method. This should answer both questions.

Comment: does this mean that in that memory space (a specific memory address) there will be other memory addresses (other memory spaces) for each variable? If that's the case then it would be clear to me.

Comment: Don't quite get what you are asking. But it may help you looking at the Equals implementation used when you mean by "comparing" using Equals. https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/ValueType.cs,d8b9b308e644b983,references

Comment: "there will be other memory addresses [...] for each variable" - yes, basically a struct defines an offset for each of its fields from the start address of the struct.